# Is Pi 4 in Access Point mode slower than as a WiFi client?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point

I see multiple sources that confirm that the Pi 4 can reach practical WiFi transfer speeds of ~100 Mbps as a WiFi client.

When I follow [this tutorial on turning it into a wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#ap-config), however, I seem unable to make `hostapd` start unless I select one of the explicitly supported channels, which all have a 20 MHz bandwidth. Higher bandwidth channels are disabled or not listed, neither of which `hostapd` seems to accept on launch.

With a 20 MHz channel I've read in other answers here that you'd get around 70 Mbps max, at least with `hw_mode=a` if I understood correctly, leading to the question: are there different speed limits when used as an AP compared to as a WiFi client?

While I succeed in connecting to this newly created AP on channel 36 with `hw_mode=a` it's only with a solid 802.11n 5 GHz 54 Mbps, in contrast to e.g. the alleged 802.11n 2.4 GHz ~100 Mbps [in this GitHub comment](https://github.com/RaspAP/raspap-webgui/issues/454#issuecomment-568272582).

What does that mean in this context? That higher speeds are attainable if I don't use `hw_mode=a`? Is using 2.4 GHz more beneficial in this use case?

The client I test with is right next to the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve 90-100Mps when set as AP.
But it seems to be a balancing act between allowing more clients
or higher throughput, as when I configured it allowing more throughput
generally only one client managed to remain connected.

I am using [RaspAP](https://github.com/RaspAP/raspap-webgui) and this is my most stable hostapd.conf
You can expect to be able to connect 2 clients where if one is at 60Mps
the other is still able to achieve 10MPs.

most stable hostapd.conf

```
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
auth_algs=1
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
beacon_int=100
ssid=YOURSSID
channel=36
hw_mode=a
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
wpa_passphrase=YOURPASSWORD
interface=wlan0
wpa=2
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
country_code=PT
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

If you only have 1 client to connect to your PI as AP, here you can exploit
a much faster connection, but concurrent downloads may be affected in my experience. I am not an expert so this has been findings with trial and error.

The config looks like this hostapd.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
auth_algs=1
beacon_int=100

country_code=PT

interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

macaddr_acl=0

logger_syslog=0
logger_syslog_level=4
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0

hw_mode=a
wmm_enabled=1

# N
ieee80211n=1
require_ht=1
ht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CCK-40]

# AC
ieee80211ac=1
require_vht=1
ieee80211d=0
ieee80211h=0
vht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][SHORT-GI-80]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
channel=36
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
ssid=YOURPASSWORD
wpa_passphrase=YOURPASSWORD
interface=wlan0
wpa=2
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

Notes that may be affecting overall speed of my configuration:

That one will allow your client to connect to the PI4 at 422Mps
with this configuration I have seen speeds of 90-95Mps on the client.
Problem seems to be that I have failed to 'keep this as a stable connection' when more then one client is connected to the PI.

in addition, if using an external interface (i occasionally use a TP Link T2U Plus AC600, had to install the driver) you may need a more solid power supply.

Things that may be impacting my setup and thus just an FYI:
I have a laptop connected to a wifi network, the machine has kali setup.
The laptop connection shows speed test results around 190-200Mbps.
Although the speed is good, since I am using 'dns over tls' sometimes this impacts page loading time. more on this later.

I share this Wifi connection, using the NetworkManager on kali, via Ethernet to the RPi4.

The RPi4 is configured with raspbian bullseye.
I am sshed into the Pi installed speedtest-cli on the Pi to see how much is arriving. I observe around 150-170Mps. so the maximum the AP must be lower then this.

On the RPi4 I have installed RaspAP as mentioned above, and nextdns.
This is important for me because I wanted to ensure that all dns traffic is
encrypted before it reaches the main network which I don't trust.

Running a speedtest on a client connected to RPi4 I see around 80-95Mps single
client, and more then one client tends to fail and disconnect.

I hope this helps. I have spent over a week around the topic
perhaps someone more versed on hostapd can better explain the configs as I am
not confident that id make a good representation of what every single option does.

Side Note. Channel 48 is not as wide, but tends to be a good fallback.